# In HotChocolate, is there a way to use customized authorization?

Tags: c#, .net, hotchocolate

I'm looking for a way to use a customized method to authorize and return BOOLEAN value.

Instead of using the official way

```
descriptor.Authorize(new[] {"Admin"});
```

Is there a way to use my own service to do that? Something like

```
bool isAuthorized = _permissionService.Authorize("Admin");

descriptor.Authorize(isAuthorized);
```